# Как починить "эффект прыжка" при подъеме клавиатуры

Tags: java, android, анимация

В своем фрагменте я использую расширяемое view, которое, в зависимости от того куда юзер делает скролл, либо сворачивается, либо разворачивается.

Для понимания вот видео:

https://youtu.be/VOpT-ZGe4dw

Тут все работает как нужно, но вот если поднять клавиатуру и попробовать поскроллить, то получается вот так:

https://youtu.be/CP5zo7RSrLU

---

Насколько я понимаю, андроид видит что места на экране недостаточно и подымает экран вверх, таким образом увеличивая рабочую область. Но если расширяемое view свернуть, то андроид видит что теперь место есть и опускает activity на место. Таким образом получается такой эффект.

Что я делаю не так?
Как починить?

**Добавка**

Забыл упомянуть, что видео которые прикрепил к вопросу это используется в методе `onCreate()` такой `SoftInputMode`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

---

Если, что-то забыл - спрашивайте.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" быть может спасет. Пробовали?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид нет это не помогло, но я заметил, что вот такая комбинация `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"` отключает возможность чтоб вью элементы поднимались вверх в не зависимости от того достаточно места на экране или нет... Не пойму как поменять эти значения так, чтоб наоборот если места не достаточно, то вью элементы поднимались вверх и фиксировались там до тех пор пока клавиатура не закроется

Comment: @АндроидАндроид или думаю ведь получается, что каждый раз когда расширяемое вью открывается или закрывается то андроид пересчитывает размеры экрана и смотрит хватает места или нет, так вот я думаю может есть возможность как то сказать андроиду, чтоб он не реагировал на то, что это вью открывается или закрывается... чтоб он перестал каждый раз пересчитывать размер? Чтоб когда клава открылась он задвинул вьюхи наверх и перестал считать размеры до тех пор пока клава опять не опуститься

Comment: Какой то необьяснимый баг. Вроде в view есть метод для пересчета размеров

Comment: @Flippy Почему не объяснимый? Если я правильно понимаю, то все получается правильно, когда юзер нажимает на `EditText` то андроид видит, что места мало и задвигает все вверх, потом юзер делает скролл и `expanded view` - мое кастомное вье начинает сворачиваться , как только оно свернулось андроид видит, что теперь места достаточно и обратно опускает экран вниз... Я уже думаю о том, чтоб повесить кастомный слушатель на клавиатуру и как только она поднимается то просто сворачивать верхнюю часть экрана... не уверен, что это будет ровно работать

Comment: На данный момент решил это таким образом, поставил кастомный слушатель на открытие и закрытие клавиатуры и когда клавиатура открывается то анимированно сворачиваю ту часть экрана которую мне нужно и наоборот. Если кому то будет интересно пишите расскажу более детально